# Align item on new line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align my button below my input and I have them both in a div called card-group. I have on both elements a `width: auto;`. I am using a media query to make it mobile friendly but I don't get it to work. The input and button won't align below eachother. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/u0d1vjyw/) is the fiddle for a working example.

Html

```
<div class="card-zipcode">
    <label>Postcode</label>
    <div class="card-group">
        <input type="text" class="input-zipcode">
        <button class="btn-postnl" id="bekijken" type="submit">Bekijken</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.card-group {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.card-group input {
width: auto;
}

.btn-postnl {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
height: 40px;
width: auto;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 20px;
vertical-align: top;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-color: #ED8C00;
-webkit-appearance: none;
outline: 0;
line-height: 38px;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: 300;
color: #FFF;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out 0s;
transition: all .1s ease-out 0s;
border-radius: 3px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: none;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.card-group {

}
}
```

Comment: if you want the width: of the button to be full-width of the container, you can add `flex-direction: column;` to the `.card-group` CSS

Answer (score 4):

add this inside your media query:

```
.card-group {
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

It will change the flex behavior and make the flex-ed items align as a column and not as a row.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0d1vjyw/1/)

Comment: another option is to change the `display` property to `block` or something, but `flex-direction: column` makes it look gorgeous.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Itay Ganor's approach works if you want to keep everything relative and completely flexible. Alternatively, you could do the following:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
     .btn-postnl {
          position: absolute;
          margin: 60px 0px;
     }
}
```

Note that you can also use this approach by using @media with Itay's approach if you want to keep the layout you had previously and only apply the change when a certain device pixel width is met.